# Regex expression to mach one of many strings in php

Tags: php, regex

I am totally new to regex , I want to match if the value is any one of the following

> cs,ch,es,ee,it,me

Till now I have tried

```
if (preg_match("/^[cs|ch|es|ee|it|me]{2}$/",$val))
    echo "true";
else
    echo "false";
```

Its working fine for true cases but also returns true for reverse of them like `sc,hc` etc.
Also it will be really helpful if you refer some good source/books to learn it for PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `()` insteadof `[]`

```
/^(cs|ch|es|ee|it|me)$/
```

**Note:** While using parentheses do not use `{2}`

So your Final code is:

```
if (preg_match("/^(cs|ch|es|ee|it|me)$/",$val))
    echo "true";
else
    echo "false";
```

TO learn regex for php I will suggest [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368608/what-are-the-best-places-to-learn-regular-expression-php) book its a good one for quick refere or refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368608/what-are-the-best-places-to-learn-regular-expression-php) question for more.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the character class `[]` from your regex and wrap them using `()`. Also remove the `{2}` as its not necessary anymore.

```
if (preg_match("/^(cs|ch|es|ee|it|me)$/",$val))
```

And this will do for you.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the grouping delimiters (parentheses). The character class delimiters (square brackets) are used for matching ranges of characters.

```
/^(cs|ch|es|ee|it|me)$/
```

If you only use the regular expressions to match something (and not *capture* anything) then you can use the `(?:)` grouping.

```
/^(?:cs|ch|es|ee|it|me)$/
```

One of the better websites for learning regular expressions is [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info).

Answer (score 0):

do you know what [] does ?

lets take an example [abcdef]

it will match any of the letters mentioned in the square brackets, suppose you are providing : `^[cs|ch|es|ee|it|me]{2}$`

it will match a single character in the list `cs|heitm`
you can add a single letter howsoever times you want but it will match only once.

so it will match any word of `two letters` as you have mentioned starting with the letters `cs|heitm`

so it will match `cs` `hs` `|s` etc.

hope you understand it :)

the corrected regex should be

```
/^(cs|ch|es|ee|it|me)$/
```

this will match for exact literal words rather than letters.